# Excecute function after OnPostExecute from AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-asynctask

In my MainActivity code I start a BackgroundTask to write data from my SQLite to a MySQL database.  So far everything goes well.

In the code after I call the BackgroundTask I delete the Record, but that is the problem.  The record is send to the MySQL database and the record is deleted, but when there went something wrong with the transfer to the MySQL database the record also will be deleted.  After searching I found that I had to call the execution of the deleting record in the part where the code is added onPostExecute.  That is the problem.  I can't find how to do this.  Can someone help me with this last point of my first app.  Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnAddNewRecord;
SQLiteHelper sQLiteHelper;
LinearLayout parentLayout;
LinearLayout layoutDisplayPeople;
TextView tvNoRecordsFound;
private TextView finalResult;
private String rowID = null;

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getAllWidgets();
    sQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(MainActivity.this);
    bindWidgetsWithEvent();
    displayAllRecords();

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String locatie = data.getStringExtra(Constants.LOCATIE);
        String product = data.getStringExtra(Constants.PRODUCT);
        String kleurwaaier = data.getStringExtra(Constants.KLEURWAAIER);
        String kleur = data.getStringExtra(Constants.KLEUR);
        String inhoud = data.getStringExtra(Constants.INHOUD);

        ContactModel contact = new ContactModel();
        contact.setLocatie(locatie);
        contact.setProduct(product);
        contact.setKleurwaaier(kleurwaaier);
        contact.setKleur(kleur);
        contact.setInhoud(inhoud);

        if (requestCode == Constants.ADD_RECORD) {
            //sQLiteHelper.insertRecord(locatie, product, kleurwaaier, kleur, inhoud);
            sQLiteHelper.insertRecord(contact);
        } else if (requestCode == Constants.UPDATE_RECORD) {
            contact.setID(rowID);
            //sQLiteHelper.updateRecord(locatie, product, kleurwaaier, kleur, inhoud, rowID);
            sQLiteHelper.updateRecord(contact);
        }
        displayAllRecords();
    }
}

private void getAllWidgets() {
    btnAddNewRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewRecord);

    parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    layoutDisplayPeople = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDisplayPeople);

    tvNoRecordsFound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNoRecordsFound);
    finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
}

private void bindWidgetsWithEvent() {
    btnAddNewRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onAddRecord();
        }
    });
}

private void onAddRecord() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TableManipulationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.DML_TYPE, Constants.INSERT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.ADD_RECORD);
}

private void onUpdateRecord(String locatie, String product, String kleurwaaier, String kleur, String inhoud) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TableManipulationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATIE, locatie);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.PRODUCT, product);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.KLEURWAAIER, kleurwaaier);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.KLEUR, kleur);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.INHOUD, inhoud);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.DML_TYPE, Constants.UPDATE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.UPDATE_RECORD);

}

private void displayAllRecords() {

    com.rey.material.widget.LinearLayout inflateParentView;
    parentLayout.removeAllViews();

    ArrayList<ContactModel> contacts = sQLiteHelper.getAllRecords();

    if (contacts.size() > 0) {
        tvNoRecordsFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ContactModel contactModel;
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {

            contactModel = contacts.get(i);

            final Holder holder = new Holder();
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.inflate_record, null);
            inflateParentView = (com.rey.material.widget.LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.inflateParentView);

            holder.tvFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);

            view.setTag(contactModel.getID());
            holder.locatie = contactModel.getLocatie();
            holder.product = contactModel.getProduct();
            holder.kleurwaaier = contactModel.getKleurwaaier();
            holder.kleur = contactModel.getKleur();
            holder.inhoud = contactModel.getInhoud();
            String personName = holder.locatie + "\n" + holder.product + "\n" + holder.kleurwaaier + " " + holder.kleur + " - [ " + holder.inhoud + "/4 ]";
            holder.tvFullName.setText(personName);

            final CharSequence[] items = {Constants.UPDATE, Constants.DELETE};
            inflateParentView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (which == 0) {

                                rowID = view.getTag().toString();
                                onUpdateRecord(holder.locatie, holder.product, holder.kleurwaaier, holder.kleur, holder.inhoud.toString());
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialogOk = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                deleteDialogOk.setTitle("Verwijder Product ?");
                                deleteDialogOk.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                //sQLiteHelper.deleteRecord(view.getTag().toString());
                                                ContactModel contact = new ContactModel();
                                                contact.setID(view.getTag().toString());
                                                sQLiteHelper.deleteRecord(contact);
                                                displayAllRecords();
                                            }
                                        }
                                );
                                deleteDialogOk.setNegativeButton("Terug", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    }
                                });
                                deleteDialogOk.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            parentLayout.addView(view);
        }
    } else {
        tvNoRecordsFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();
}

public void userReg(View view) {

    ArrayList<ContactModel> contacts = sQLiteHelper.getAllRecords();

    if (contacts.size() > 0) {
        ContactModel contactModel;
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {

            contactModel = contacts.get(i);
            final Holder holder = new Holder();
            //final View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.inflate_record, null);
            //inflateParentView = (com.rey.material.widget.LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.inflateParentView);

            holder.tvFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);

            view.setTag(contactModel.getID());
            holder.locatie = contactModel.getLocatie();
            holder.product = contactModel.getProduct();
            holder.kleurwaaier = contactModel.getKleurwaaier();
            holder.kleur = contactModel.getKleur();
            holder.inhoud = contactModel.getInhoud();

            String id = "test";
            String locatie = holder.locatie.toString();
            String product = holder.product.toString();
            String kleurwaaier = holder.kleurwaaier.toString();
            String kleur = holder.kleur.toString();
            String inhoud = holder.inhoud.toString();

            String method = "register";

            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
            backgroundTask.execute(method, id, locatie, product, kleurwaaier, kleur, inhoud);

            //String status = backgroundTask.getStatus().toString();
            /*
            ContactModel contact = new ContactModel();
            contact.setID(view.getTag().toString());

            sQLiteHelper.deleteRecord(contact);
            displayAllRecords();
           */
        }

    }

}

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://xxx/register.php";

        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String id = params[1];
            String locatie = params[2];
            String product = params[3];
            String kleurwaaier = params[4];
            String kleur = params[5];
            String inhoud = params[6];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("locatie", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(locatie, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("product", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(product, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("kleurwaaier", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(kleurwaaier, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("kleur", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(kleur, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("inhoud", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(inhoud, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Success...";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("Registration Success...")) {
            //Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finalResult.setText(result);

            ContactModel contact = new ContactModel();
            contact.setID(view.getTag().toString());

            sQLiteHelper.deleteRecord(contact);

        } else {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

}


public String getText() {
    finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    String text = finalResult.getText().toString();
    return text;
}

private class Holder {
    TextView tvFullName;
    String locatie;
    String product;
    String kleurwaaier;
    String kleur;
    String inhoud;
}
```

}

Comment: The last few lines of your code contain the onPostExecute function. Put your deletion there.

Comment: Indeed thats the place to be but the problem is that I don't know how to do.  If I add sQLiteHelper.deleteRecord(contact); then the parameter contact is not known there

Comment: You can put the entire `BackgroundTask` class inside the function that calls it so it has access to those variables.

Comment: I think I have to change the first words public class from the BackgroundTask.  When I copy the entire class I see the note :  'Modifier public not allowed here'

Comment: If you put the `userReg` method within the `MainActivity` class then you won't have this issue. It was a little hard to see the hierarchy of your code because of formatting.

Comment: I changed the above code like I have it now.  If understand it well the userReg is already inside the MainActivity.  The problem with the public class from BackgroundTask is still the same.

Comment: If `userReg` is within `MainActivity` then you can put `BackgroundTask` within `MainActivity` as well. I don't think you need the `BackgroundTask` to be `public`, as you aren't calling it from another `class`.

Comment: That's where I started.  I changed above code again like I have it now and added  in onPostExecute contact.setID(view.getTag().toString());  There is now a problem with view